# Easy Movie Texture and Google Cardboard Buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm making an app for 360° video with Google Cardboard. I have the Easy Movie Texture plugin, but I can't find the way to make a UI. The controls appear on the left side. Is there a way to make them appear with the movement of the head?

Answer (score 1):

create a canvas and attach as child of CardboardMain.

I use this method along with a reticle canvas to allow selection via gaze